# WPF popup with textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a control that displays search results as a user types something in a textbox. For this, I have a textbox and a popup that shows up when the user types something into it (just like a google search box). Like so,

```
<Grid> <TextBox Name="userEntry" /> <Popup /> </Grid>
```

Now when the user starts typing into the textbox i want the popup to show and stay open until the user focusses on some other ui control or if the text entered is empty.
I am unable to achieve this easily and was wondering if there are alternate better ways of doing this in wpf.
Regards

Comment: Alternate to what? You didn't show your way so how can we know what's an alternative?

Comment: I did...I wanted a google like search box capability where I type soemthing in the textbox, I show a popup right below it that lists the results..but im having trouble with focus issues etc...another alternative Im looking into is...restyleing a combobox to achieve something similiar.

Answer (score 2):

XAML :

```
  <Window>
     <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition />
             <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Open Search Window"  Height="30" Width="150" Click="btn_Click"/> 

        <Popup x:Name="popup"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}" Placement="Bottom"  Width="200" Height="100" Margin="0,20,0,0">
           <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="AliceBlue">
               <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,15,0"/> 
           </Border>
        </Popup>

        <TextBox x:Name="focusTarger" Text="Focus Me !" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>

    </Grid> 
  </Window>
```

CS :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GotFocus += MainWindow_GotFocus;
    }

    void MainWindow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;

        if (txtBox == element || popup == element || element.Parent == popup)
            return;

        popup.IsOpen = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text);
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks eran! Let me try this and see.